# JHipster Microservice Application with a PostgreSQL Microservice (with Pagination) and a Cassandra Microservice (without Pagination)

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, microservices, jhipster

Is it possible to have a microservice application in JHipster that has two microservices: one with a PostgreSQL backend and one with a Cassandra backend? If so, could I have pagination enabled for the PostgreSQL entities and disabled for the Cassandra entities in their respective microservies? I would disable the pagination for the Cassandra microservice since I get the error "Pagination isn't allowed when the application used Cassandra". However, is there a way around this error; i.e., could my PostgreSQL microservice still use pagination - even though my Cassandra microservice does not?

My best,
Amar

Comment: Yes you can, pagination is an option per entity. Have you tried?

Comment: I had to comment out the ```paginate GnGeoname, GnAdmin1CodeAscii, GnAdmin2Code, GnAlternateName, GnContinentCode, GnCountryInfo, GnHierarchy, GnFeatureCode, GnIsoLanguageCode, GnPostalCode, GnTimeZone with pagination``` line from my apps.jh file to remedy the ```Pagination isn't allowed when the application used Cassandra``` error message.  Is there a way to specify pagination per entity in the .jh file?

Comment: Yes just repeat paginate, see the JDL doc, or alternatively you can exclude pagination on some entities like in https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/options#all--example-with-exclusions-unary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the `paginate` option into the `application {...}` object.

```
application {
  config {
    baseName geonamesservice,
    packageName com.saathratri.geonames,
    applicationType microservice,
    authenticationType oauth2,
    databaseType sql,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    serverPort 8081,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
  }
  entities GnGeoname, GnAdmin1CodeAscii, GnAdmin2Code, GnAlternateName, GnContinentCode, GnCountryInfo, GnHierarchy, GnFeatureCode, GnIsoLanguageCode, GnPostalCode, GnTimeZone

  paginate GnGeoname, GnAdmin1CodeAscii, GnAdmin2Code, GnAlternateName, GnContinentCode, GnCountryInfo, GnHierarchy, GnFeatureCode, GnIsoLanguageCode, GnPostalCode, GnTimeZone with pagination
}
```